# Priority between properties in HibernateJPAVendorAdapter and JPAProperty

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, configuration

I have the following configuration in an application Spring + JPA + Hibernate, using packagesToScan to avoid having file persistence.xml.

```
<!-- Configure JPA Implementation -->
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
      <property name="database" value="${jpa.database}" />
      <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.showSql}" />
      <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.dialect}" />
      <property name="generateDdl" value="${jpa.generateDdl}" />
</bean>

<!-- Create the JPA EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
      <property name="packagesToScan">
           <list>
               <value>com.proyectofinal.model</value>
           </list>
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperty">  
           <props>  
               <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>  
               <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>  
               <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>  
               <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />  
               <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />  
               <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />  
               <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect" />  
               <entry key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>  
           </props>  
      </property>  
</bean>
```

My question is:

- Is it necessary define in both places properties like show_sql or dialect?
- Which one has priority over the other?
- What place is more appropriate to define it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties specified in the `JpaVendorAdapter` don't have to be duplicated in the list of additional properties. If that would be the case the `JpaVendorAdapter` would be pretty useless.

Also in your configuration use either `database` or `databasePlatform` don't use both.

Properties which can be configured by using a `JpaVendorAdapter` I would configure right there, it would save you a couple of lines and you don't have to remember the cryptic hibernate (or which ever provider you use) property name.

The properties you need are the following.

```
<props>  
   <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>  
   <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>  
   <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>  
   <entry key="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />  
   <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />  
   <entry key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>  
</props>
```

If you define them in both places the one from the `JpaVendorAdapter` are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @M. Deinum's answer, if you decide to use the `jpaProperties` over `jpaVendorAdapter`, you'll need to set the `persistenceProvider` property since it would normally be derived from `jpaVendorAdapter`

for example

```
<property name="persistenceProvider">
  <bean class="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
</property>
```

Also, `jpaProperty` should be `jpaProperties`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! 

Especifying HibernateJPAVendorAdapter wouldn´t it be enought?

Comment: I'm just saying if you were to set `jpaProperties` alone without setting `jpaVendorAdaptor`, then you'd need to set `persistenceProvider`. Specifying a default jpaVendorAdaptor (ie. one without properties) may also be enough, although I've never tried it.

Comment: Fine!! I didn't undestand well. Now I did!! Thanks